# Insert for each parameter element

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables:

> OnlineUsers (SessionId, UserId)

and

> UserPings (Id, UserId, Type)

Id's are uniqueidentifiers and Type is int.

Using a SessionId and a list of ints, i need to insert entries in UserPings where one doesnt already exists.. My current issue is that OnlineUsers.UserId can potentially be NULL but also my hackey way to insert from the ints list.

The code below doesn't work because of error with case, but it should hopefully give an idea of the direction i am heading.

```
DECLARE @userId uniqueidentifier;
SET @userId = (SELECT UserId from OnlineUsers WHERE Id=@sessionId);
DECLARE @pingTT table (typeId int);
INSERT @pingTT(typeId) values(1),(2),(3); 
CASE WHEN (@userId IS NOT NULL) 
THEN
    INSERT INTO [UserPingStatuses] (Id, UserId, Type)
    SELECT NEWID(), @userId, typeId FROM @pingTT
    WHERE typeId IN @pingTypes AND
    NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM UserPingStatuses WHERE UserId=@userId AND Type=typeId
    )
END
```

The parameter `@pingTypes` is added as `(@pingTypes1, @pingTypes2, ...)` by dapper I assume.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
IF (@userId IS NOT NULL) 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [UserPingStatuses] (Id, UserId, Type)
    SELECT NEWID(), @userId, typeId FROM @pingTT
    WHERE typeId IN @pingTypes AND
    NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM UserPingStatuses WHERE UserId=@userId AND Type=typeId
    )
END
```

`CASE` is only valid in a SELECT, WHERE, ON, ORDER BY statement.